# Why can I not catch undefined variable Error

Tags: exception, tcl

Why does the below code not catch error:

```
rename list _native_list
proc list {args} {
  uplevel 1 {
    if { [catch {_native_list $args} val] } {
      puts "list $args :: FAILED $val"
    } else {
      return $val
    }
  }
}
```

When trying to execute the newly defined list command, this is what I get:

```
% list hi $h
can't read "h": no such variable
```

Why did it not trap the error?

Comment: Arguments are evaluated before the proc is.

Comment: FWIW, you'd probably be happier using `trace add execution` for that sort of thing. Wrapping commands wholesale like that is easy to get wrong.

Comment: @Shawn I would like to trap such commands referencing undefined variables in a large TCL file without halting execution of the TCL file. How do I go about this?

Comment: @backstreetrover Seems like a follow-up question, your actual question was answered already. Executing or evaluating a Tcl script while accepting or working around non-existing and undefined variables will break the script, unless the script has an overly simplistic data flow etc. See my answer on a static analysis approach.

Answer (score 3):

The proc isn't even getting called.  The error is happening when the `$h` argument in the argument is evaluated.  `$h` is undefined, so you can't send that as an argument to the proc.

Comment: ok, then how do I trap the error in this case? Essentially I would like to source a TCL file which has a bunch of missing var declarations which are subsequently used in [list $var] commands. I do not want to stop on first missing var, but want script to continue sourcing till the end trapping any missing variable declarations earlier on. @Chris Heithoff

Comment: You need to pass the variable name instead of the variable value into the proc.   

Instead of [list $h], you should do [list h].    The string 'h' can be passed into the proc even if a variable named 'h' does not exist.

Because you're using uplevel, then your catch statement will be run at the execution stack where the proc was called.  How well do you understand 'uplevel'?

Comment: this is not what I intend to do. I have a TCL file with many commands such as `set xyz  [list $abc]` Some of the variable declarations are missing, but I want to source the whole file without aborting at the first missing variable declaration.

Comment: In that case you will have to split the file into individual commands (using `split` and `info complete`) and execute each one while catching errors. An additional complication is going to be if you want to support commands that may evaluate their arguments, such as `if` and `foreach`.

Comment: It sounds like you're not allowed to edit the .tcl file that is throwing errors when you're sourcing it....or maybe you just don't want to.   Why not initialize all these variables to "undefined" before sourcing the .tcl file?

Comment: Yes, I am not allowed to edit the TCL file. This is part of a larger script which takes in a TCL file as input and is expected to execute everything in the TCL file if possible just skipping commands which fail due to undeclared variables etc. The reason I cannot pre-declare vars is because I do not know all the variables to define them upfront. There are likely 1000s of them. 
Essentially all I want is 'do not abort on error' feature while sourcing the TCL file (which I do not own). Seems like this can't be done.

Comment: There's a simple fix.  Just wrap the source command in a catch command:

 `catch [source abc.tcl]`

Comment: The problem with catch on whole script is that it will return after the first undeclared var without sourcing the lines below the undeclared var.

Comment: Interesting, I was testing in Synopsys EDA tool that has a Tcl shell, not the native tclsh.   The Synopysys version of source will continue on error inside a catch statement.

Answer (score 2):

A first step, rather than DIY, is to use a static program analyzer, e.g., [`nagelfar`](http://nagelfar.sourceforge.net/). It supports some detection of references to non-existing and uninitialized (a.k.a. undefined in Tcl lingo) variables.

For a file `t.tcl` with content:

```
namespace eval ::ns1 {
    list $i
}

proc foo {h} {
    list $h
}
```

`nagelfar` yields true positives:

```
% ./tclkit nagelfar132.kit t.tcl
Checking file t.tcl
Line   2: E Unknown variable "i"
Line   6: E Unknown variable "h"
```

But, beware, Tcl does not fully lean itself towards static analyses of this sort, `nagelfar` will yield false positives in case of computed variable names, computed formal arguments lists to `proc`s etc.

Dynamic approaches by partially (re-)evaluating a script to record such variable references will likely break even scripts of low complexity to a point making the results worthless, if any at all.

Comment: I'd wish [`tclquadcode`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tclquadcode)'s infrastructure would be reused to provide a successor to `nagelfar`, this would be a great step forward.

Comment: I have a script which accepts a TCL file as input. It is understood that this TCL file has some missing var declarations, so it won't source clean all they way through. What I want is for it to source every command that can be sourced while skipping commands which fail due to missing var declarations. I guess I could pre-process this TCL with a static analyzer, delete the lines which the analyzer thinks is an issue and then finally source the modified TCL file. However this seems overkill, and I was hoping for a simpler solution of trapping errors. Looks like, I can't easily do that.

Comment: So use `nagelfar` to process that "Tcl file".

Comment: I should add that I do not see a point in skipping the commands which might fail on missing variables' values. It is not the commands fault ...