# Set default value for every undefined variable in TCL while accessing (reading) the variables

Tags: tcl

While accessing undefined variable in tcl I will get the message like :
"can't read "KKK": no such variable"

I want to set default value for every undefined variable and I am sure the manipulation is what I want.
I've tried several solutions but no one can satisfy me.

1. *trace add variable* : only could set specific variable name. I want set default value for "all" undefined variables and I do not know their name in advance.
2. *unknown* : It seems accessing undefined variable will not call this proc ?

Anyone could help ?

Comment: Writing a procedure that uses [`exists`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/info+exists) should do the trick, have you tried?

Comment: I do not know whether the variable is declared in advance, so it's impossible to do info exists for certain variable name.

Comment: Well info exists tells you if it is declared or not. So if it isn't declared you `set` a default value. Where is the issue with that?

Comment: The scenario is I need to source a huge tcl file (I cannot modify it) and thousands of variables in it are undeclared. Provider claims that I can set them as any value and the result will correct. Now the question is : how can I do that ?

Comment: That depends on how the file is structured and you haven't shown an example. But you will need to learn about [namespace](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M9) I guess

Comment: After that look into [`info vars`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm)

Comment: I know about `namespace` and `info vars`, but cannot figure out how to achieve what I want. May you explain more about it ?

Comment: I've found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356539/why-can-i-not-catch-undefined-variable-error) is the same as my scenario, but in that discussion no available solution is shown. The description about Synopsys tool is also incorrect (I've tried on PrimeTime)

Comment: Setting every variable that could exist to have a default value seems like a very bad idea. Or at least really impractical. You'd need to at least know what sort of value to default a particular variable to. Some might like an empty string, others `0` or `0.0` or `false` or... I suspect you need to do the work of working out what is really supposed to be there.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend calling variables `KKK`

Comment: I am sure the manipulation is what I want, so please just talk about the idea to achieve it.